# Unity code issues. Character is not moving

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a class that is responsible for controlling a character. But the code in this class does not work.

```
private ObjectSequence Patrocle;

public bool moving = false;
private float moveAxis = 0;
public float accelaration = 0.1f;
public float moveSpeed = 10f;

public Rigidbody2D rBody;

private Dictionary<KeyCode, bool> pressed = new Dictionary<KeyCode, bool>();

void Start()
{
    pressed.Add(KeyCode.LeftArrow, false);
    pressed.Add(KeyCode.RightArrow, false);
    Patrocle = GetComponent<ObjectSequence>();
}

private void FixedUpdate()
{
    moving = pressed[KeyCode.LeftArrow] ^ pressed[KeyCode.RightArrow];
    if (moving)
    {
        moveAxis += pressed[KeyCode.RightArrow] ? accelaration : (accelaration * -1f);
        moveAxis = Mathf.Clamp(moveAxis, -1, 1);
        rBody.velocity = new Vector2(moveAxis * moveSpeed, rBody.velocity.y);
    }
    else
        moveAxis = 0f;
}
```

It should move right, but it does not make anything absent. What is the problem?

Comment: How do you check if left arrow or right arrow is pressed? They will always be false in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does not move because you are confusing `KeyCode` with a mean to detect if a key is pressed or not.

`KeyCode.LeftArrow` is just a value designating the left arrow key. It won't change if the left arrow key is pressed.

More precisely, the issue lies in the following line:

```
moving = pressed[KeyCode.LeftArrow] ^ pressed[KeyCode.RightArrow];
```

Try the following instead:

```
moving = (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftArrow)) ^ (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.RightArrow))
```

Comment: He's trying to do an exclusive OR though.

Comment: oh yes your completely right :D was so into bitwise stuff that week that I forgot this works on bools as well ^^